# RVIZ not visualizing all markers

Tags: ros, rviz, markerarray

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create two markers and add them to a MarkerArray and then publish it. However, only the last marker shows up. Any help with this is much appreciated!

```
pub = rospy.Publisher('site_markers', MarkerArray, queue_size=10)
rospy.init_node('mission_manager')

markerArray = MarkerArray
  
marker1 = Marker()
marker1.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
marker1.header.frame_id = "/vicon"
marker1.type = marker1.CYLINDER
marker1.action = marker1.ADD
marker1.pose.position.x = -9
marker1.pose.position.y = 0
marker1.pose.position.z = 0
marker1.scale.x = 1.0
marker1.scale.y = 1.0
marker1.scale.z = 0.01
marker1.color.r = 1.0
marker1.color.g = 0
marker1.color.b = 0
marker1.color.a = 0.7
marker1.lifetime = rospy.Duration.from_sec(0)
marker1.frame_locked = 0
markerArray.markers.append(marker1)

marker2 = Marker()
marker2.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
marker2.header.frame_id = "/vicon"
marker2.type = marker2.CYLINDER
marker2.action = marker2.ADD
marker2.pose.position.x = -5
marker2.pose.position.y = 4
marker2.pose.position.z = 0
marker2.scale.x = 1.0
marker2.scale.y = 1.0
marker2.scale.z = 0.01
marker2.color.r = 1.0
marker2.color.g = 0
marker2.color.b = 0
marker2.color.a = 0.7
marker2.lifetime = rospy.Duration.from_sec(0)
marker2.frame_locked = 0
markerArray.markers.append(marker2)

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    pub.publish(markerArray)
```

Also when I do rostopic echo on the topic, it shows both markers being published, so that confused me as well.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236818/rviz-not-visualizing-all-markers/) by [Thalaiva](https://answers.ros.org/users/23196/thalaiva/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2016-06-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're not setting the `id` field (see [docs/api/visualization_msgs/Marker](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/Marker.html)), so it will default to `0` and makes both your markers use the same id. RViz receives a message containing a marker with the same id, and interprets it as an 'update' to the same marker it saw before. Result: you see only a single marker.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thalaiva](https://answers.ros.org/users/23196/thalaiva/) on 2016-06-13**:
This fixed it, thank you!